# Rules in .htaccess only if the requested URL is /wp-admin

Tags: htaccess, security

I want these lines from my `.htaccess` to execute only if the URL is not `/wp-admin`:

```sh
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
Header add Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self';"
```

My idea was something like this:

```sh
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin">

</If>
<Else>
  Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
  Header add Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self';"
</Else>
```

Maybe it would be nice if a logged in user is on the website that the lines also not be executed.

Comment: Have a look at the [`wp_headers`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/) filter.

Comment: I need to do it with htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution. I think in my first try my regex was wrong.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/wp-admin/#">
    
</If>
<Else>
Header add Content-Security-Policy "style-src 'self'"
Header add Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self'"
</Else>
```

Comment: Why use an empty `If` with an `Else` rather than `!~` instead of `=~`?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this instead:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} !~ m#\s/wp-admin#">
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
Header add Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self';"
</If>
```

This should set the two headers only when the requested URL does *not* start with `/wp-admin`.

The check is against `THE_REQUEST` (as opposed to `REQUEST_URI`) since `REQUEST_URI` changes when the URL is rewritten by the WordPress front-controller. `THE_REQUEST` is the first line of the request headers (a string of the form `GET /wp-admin/something HTTP/1.1`) and does not change when the request is rewritten.

> Maybe it would be nice if a loggedin user is on the website that the lines also not be executed.
> (I need to do it with htaccess.)

You can't reliably do this with `.htaccess`. In `.htaccess` you can only determine whether the authentication cookie is set, not whether it is set correctly.